# Sending base class to a method which receives derived class - c#

Tags: c#, inheritance, polymorphism

I have a Base class and 2 derived classes.  I have a variable of base class which can hold one of the derived classes.  I want to send that variable to a method which receives derived classes.

What can I do to resolve this problem without explicit cast since I don't know what the variable holds?

code:

```cs
Class A{ 
    virtual public void foo1() {/.../}
}
Class B : A{
    override public void foo1() {/.../}
}
Class C : A{
    override public void foo1() {/.../}
}
Class D{
   public foo(B argB) {/.../}
   public foo(C argC) {/.../}   

// in main
D varD = new D();
A varA = new B();   

varD.foo(varA); //--->> Problem here need explicit casting
A varC = new C();
varD.foo(varC);  //--->> Problem here need explicit casting
```

I don't know what derived class I'm sending to `varD.foo` and I want different handling of different derived classes.  What can I do?

Comment: Does this code compile? I don't see any declaration of varB.

Comment: Try something like the [visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern).

Comment: AbZy, sorry it was my mistake, I fixed the code

Comment: Depending upon what your `D` overloads of `foo` are doing, you might be in a position to consider a visitor pattern, or another collaborator that otherwise knows what to do with different subclasses of `A`.

Comment: Why I do have a sinking feeling that `foo(B argB)` contains `argB.foo1()`? Refactor to take advantage of polymorphism.

Answer (score 3):

This is not what polymorphism is about - you can not pass a base class where a specialized class is expected, even when explicitly casting. Polymorphism works the other way: You can pass a specialized class wherever the base class is expected.

What you should do is make `D.foo` expect `A` and you will automatically be fine. If you add any methods to `B` or `C` which have no base implementation in `A`,  you need to pass `B` anyway and can not cast an `A` to `B` or `D`.

Comment: If `D` does something special based on `B` or `C`, then sending them to a single method wouldn't be sufficient. Another layer of abstraction could be needed.

Comment: Thanks @Servy for editing my answer - while the edit is correct and improves my answer, I actually don't much like my answers being edited. Next time, suggest the edit in a comment please, and I will do the edit myself. So I can always be sure that what's written here is actually what I said :-)

Comment: @AnthonyPegram: Really? If `D.foo` expected `A` as a parameter an then chose the path of execution depending on `if (a is B) ... else if (a is C) ...` would that not work?

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar That's not how SO works.  This is a collaborative site, and you don't have the right to have your answers not be edited.  By posting on this site you are giving your permission for any user to edit your post.  See [this FAQ entry](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#editing) for more info.

Comment: I just *asked* you not to, because I don't like it. You may show that respect or you may not. But I still have a right to ask.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar, It would work, but it further highlights that B and C are not really substitutable for each other. Think: Liskov Substitution Principle. But if it gets you where you need to be and is relatively quarantined, then go with it. But as further subclasses are added, that chain of type checking could need to grow, and if it is spread all over your system, that's a lot of change (and a lot of areas to break).

Comment: @AnthonyPegram: Yes, I agree with that. However, passing a "real instance" of `A` where `B` or `C` are expected is really bad. If the signature of `foo` indicates to require a `B` or a `C` I expect it to invoke special features of instances of `B` or `C` - what if there are new methods in `B` or `C` that are not in `A`? By requiring `A` as a parameter I also tell that the features of `A` are enough for the method to perform properly. Still the method can do special stuff based on whether the parameter is actually a `B` or a `C`.

Comment: `A` could be a fruit. `B` could be a banana. `C` could be a cherry. `D` could be a person that is allergic to cherries. It might not be a matter of what it uses within the fruit, but what it does with the fruit. If throwing the fruit in the trash is the course of action, that's up to D (or other collaborators) to decide, and to know how to do it. It need not be a method on fruit. It can certainly use type checking to do this, but as the number of types grow, so does the method. If this is an area not prone to change, however, then maybe you go with it. It *is* a simple solution, after all.

Answer (score 2):

Just make `foo` an abstract instance method of `A` and override the implementation in `B` and `C`. You could even keep your class `D` and delegate the actual work to there but it depends if this is a good idea.

Here the code with delegation to `D`. Also note that I omitted the method `foo1()` in all classes.

```
public abstract class A
{ 
    public abstract void foo(D d);
}

public sealed class B : A
{
    public override void foo(D d)
    {
        d.foo(this);
    }
}

public sealed class C : A
{
    public override void foo(D d)
    {
        d.foo(this);
    }
}

public sealed class D
{
   public void foo(B b) { [...] }
   public void foo(C c) { [...] }   
}
```

Now you can use virtual method dispatching to call the correct method.

```
D d = new D();

A b = new B();   
A c = new C();

b.foo(d); // Calls B.foo(D) and in turn D.foo(B).
c.foo(d); // Calls C.foo(D) and in turn D.foo(C).
```

Comment: Does it matter whether it is `abstract`? `B` and `C` override the method anyway.

Comment: The methods in question are `D.foo(B)` and `D.foo(C)`, not one of the methods in the `A` hierarchy.

Comment: Ah, I see. You mean to remove class `D` entirely and have `B` and `C` implement their own `foo`.

Comment: It is not necessary to have `A` abstract - you can just have a dummy implementation. But if possible `A` should be abstract. You could get rid of `D` but there is no need to - see the added code.